# Round-Robin Arbiter Architecture from Efficient microarchitecture for network-on-chip routers

Tags: fpga, verilog

I have formally verified a round-robin arbiter code

Could anyone advise about the various methods of minimizing the combinational delay tcomb penalty mentioned at the [end of section 2.3 of Efficient microarchitecture for network-on-chip routers](https://stacks.stanford.edu/file/druid:wr368td5072/thesis-augmented.pdf#page=32) ?

```
// Credit : https://www.eevblog.com/forum/fpga/understanding-linear-implementation-of-a-round-robin-arbiter/

module arbiter #(parameter WIDTH = 4) (clk, reset, req, grant);

input clk, reset;
input [WIDTH-1:0] req;
output [WIDTH-1:0] grant; 

// 'grant' is one-hot vector, which means only one client request is granted/given green light to proceed
// note that 'base' is one-hot vector, 
// 'base' signal helps round-robin arbiter to decide which 'req' to start servicing
reg [WIDTH-1:0] base;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if(reset) base <= 1;

    else base <= (grant[WIDTH-1]) ? 1 : (grant == 0) ? base : ( grant << 1 );
end

wire [WIDTH-1:0] priority_in;
wire [(WIDTH << 1)-1:0] priority_out; // the two leftmost significant bit are left unused

wire [WIDTH-1:0] granting = req & priority_in;
wire [WIDTH-2:0] approval; // we only have (WIDTH-1) block F

genvar index;
generate
    for(index = 0; index < WIDTH; index = index + 1)
    begin
        if(index == WIDTH-1) assign grant[index] = (reset) ? 0 : granting[index];

        else assign grant[index] = (reset) ? 0 : ( granting[index] | approval[index] );


        if(index < (WIDTH-1)) assign approval[index] = priority_out[index+WIDTH-1] & req[index];

        if(index > 0) assign priority_in[index] = base[index] | priority_out[index-1];

        else assign priority_in[index] = base[index];
    end
endgenerate


genvar priority_index;
generate
    for(priority_index = 0; priority_index < (WIDTH << 1); priority_index = priority_index + 1)
    begin : out_priority    

        if(priority_index < (WIDTH))
            assign priority_out[priority_index] = (~req[priority_index]) & priority_in[priority_index];

        else assign priority_out[priority_index] = (~req[priority_index-WIDTH]) & priority_out[priority_index-1];
    end
endgenerate


`ifdef FORMAL

initial assume(reset);
initial assume(req == 0);  // only enable this assume() to test the cover() at line 100 properly

genvar grant_num;

generate 
    for(grant_num = 0; grant_num < WIDTH; grant_num = grant_num + 1)

        always @(*) cover(first_clock_had_passed && grant[grant_num]);  // covers grants to each of the clients' request

endgenerate


reg [WIDTH-1:0] req_previous;
always @(posedge clk) req_previous <= req;

always @(posedge clk) cover(!$past(reset) && (grant == 0)); // covers the ability to go to an idle state

// covers the ability to handle requests properly even with ALL requests ON
always @(posedge clk) cover((&$past(req_previous)) && (&$past(req)) && (&req) && first_clock_had_passed && $past(first_clock_had_passed) && ((grant & $past(req)) == grant)); 


reg [WIDTH-1:0] grant_previous;
always @(posedge clk) grant_previous <= grant;

always @(posedge clk) cover(grant != grant_previous); // covers the ability to switch grants to any other requests

always @(posedge clk) cover(first_clock_had_passed && $past(first_clock_had_passed) && (&req) && (req_previous == 4'b1100) && ($past(req_previous) == 4'b1011)); // covers round-robin ability
`endif

`ifdef FORMAL

reg first_clock_had_passed;
initial first_clock_had_passed = 0;

always @(posedge clk) first_clock_had_passed <= 1;

// https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2
wire multiple_requests = (req != 0) && !((req & (req - 1)) == 0);
wire grant_is_one_hot = (grant != 0) && ((grant & (grant - 1)) == 0);

always @(*)
begin
    if(reset) assert(grant == 0);

    else begin

        if (|req) assert(grant_is_one_hot);

        else assert(grant == 0);


        // assertions for round-robin capability

        if((req == req_previous) && multiple_requests) 
        // it is possible that the same client files request again after being serviced
            assert((grant & req) != grant_previous); 
    end
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if(first_clock_had_passed)
    begin
        // starts round-robin arbiter with req #0 getting prioritized first
        if($past(reset)) assert(base == 1);

        // 'grant' is a one-hot signal, but 'req' is not a one-hot signal
        // 'base' is a one-hot signal which rotates
        //  after the corresponding 'req' had been granted/given permission to proceed)
        //  Rotation wraps around upon reaching MSB

        else begin
            assert(base == $past(grant[WIDTH-1]) ? 1 : ($past(grant) == 0) ? $past(base) : ($past(grant) << 1) );
            assert(base != 0);
        end
    end
end

`endif

endmodule
```

Comment: I like questions that start with "I have formally verified…". But, considering combinatorial delay: Have you found which path is the critical one (in any critical state)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, see the arrow inside [figure 2.3 of the thesis which is on page 31](https://stacks.stanford.edu/file/druid:wr368td5072/thesis-augmented.pdf#page=31)

Comment: @MarcusMüller How could [prefix sum networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) actually replace blocks R and F ?